# How to simulate a strong correlation of data with R

Tags: r, ggpubr

Sometimes I try to simulate data by using the `rnorm` function, which I have done below:

```
mom.iq <- rnorm(n=1000,
                mean=120,
                sd=15)
kid.score <- rnorm(n=1000,
                   mean=45,
                   sd=20)
df <- data.frame(mom.iq,
                 kid.score)
```

But when I plot something like this, it usually ends up with data thats highly uncorrelated:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggscatter(df,
          x="mom.iq",
          y="kid.score")+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image: lm.pic]

However, I would like to simulate something with a stronger correlation if possible. Is there an easy way to do this within R? I'm aware that I could just as easily just produce my own values manually, but thats not super practical for recreating large samples.

Comment: This may help you: [Simulate Bivariate and Multivariate Normal Distribution in R](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simulate-bivariate-and-multivariate-normal-distribution-in-r/#:~:text=To%20simulate%20a%20Multivariate%20Normal,value%20in%20the%20R%20Language.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is to generate two independent variables; so, it is normal not to be correlated. What you can do is this:

```
# In order to make the values reproducible
  set.seed(12345)

# Generate independent variable
  x <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=120, sd=15)
# Generate the dependen variable
  y <- 3*x + 6 + rnorm(n=1000, mean = 0, sd = 5)
```

I used 3 and 6, but you can define them as you want (`a` and `b`) in order to get a linear dependence defined as `y = a*x + b`.

The sum of `rnorm(n=1000, mean = 0, sd = 5)` is done to add some variability and avoid a perfect correlation between `x` and `y`. If you want to get a more correlated data, reduce the standard deviation (`sd`) and to get a lower correlation, increase its value.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I don't know why I didn't already consider just adding a constant value to the `rnorm` function, but that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can also modify its `mean` and replace it by a 6, so that you can delete the 6 before the rnorm(n=1000, mean = 0, sd = 5). I just wrote like that to see which is the expected linear regression model.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your second variable by taking the first variable into account, and adding some error with `rnorm` in order to avoid making the relationship completely deterministic/

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(father_age = rnorm(1000, 35, 5)) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(child_score = -father_age * 0.5 + rnorm(1000, 0, 4))

dat |> 
  ggplot(aes(father_age, child_score)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you don't just want to simulate arbitrary `x` and `y` with a linear relationship (which the other two answers show). You give your variables meaningful names `mod.iq` and `kid.score`, so it appears to me that you want them to have certain mean and variance. In this case, you can use `MASS::mvrnorm` to simulate samples from multivariate normal, where you can specify correlation. This allows you to preserve the marginal mean and marginal variance you specified.

```
## your current specification of marginal mean and marginal standard deviation
mean_mod.iq <- 120
mean_kid.score <- 45
sd_mod.iq <- 15
sd_kid.score <- 20

## introduce correlation coefficient between two variables
## coefficient must be between -1 and 1
corcoef <- 0.8
## the result covariance between two variables
covariance <- corcoef * sd_mod.iq * sd_kid.score

## the variance-covariance matrix
Sigma <- matrix(c(sd_mod.iq^2, covariance, covariance, sd_kid.score^2), nrow = 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  225  240
#[2,]  240  400
```

Now you can use `MASS::mvrnorm`.

```
xy <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 500, mu = c(mean_mod.iq, mean_kid.score), Sigma = Sigma)
colnames(xy) <- c("mod.iq", "kid.score")
xydf <- data.frame(xy)
head(xydf)
#    mod.iq kid.score
#1 111.6211  33.26241
#2 114.4765  42.49280
#3 115.8160  47.57242
#4 121.8656  53.16578
#5 152.1459  89.60617
#6 107.4360  39.00345

plot(xydf)
```

You can verify marginal mean and marginal variance of the simulated samples.

```
sapply(xydf, mean)  ## mean, you specified 120 and 45
#   mod.iq kid.score 
# 119.9499   44.4193 

sapply(xydf, sd)  ## standard error, you specified 15 and 20
#   mod.iq kid.score 
# 15.35214  20.16483
```

[image: xyplot]

Comment: Yeah I think I realize the distinction now in what you were saying.